# How to use React to setState and avoid recursion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I'm using React with a Flask server, and have a table where a user can enter information. This child table updates the `tableData` state of the MainApp when the user edits a cell, adds a new row, deletes a row etc.

My problem is that I'm using an `image` state in the MainApp to store the image URL (this URL contains the hash as well so it changes every time a client requests for information). However, I'm also using the `tableData` state in the MainApp to store the table information which changes when a user updates the table. This calls `componentWillUpdate` which in turn gets the image blob, converts it to a URL and updates the state `image`. This in turn calls `componentWillUpdate` as you might imagine leading to a recursive call. The [React documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html) says to not call `setState` inside `componentWillUpdate`. I'm curious as to what the recommended way of doing this is.

My intended behaviour is that the user edits a cell on the table, MainApp sends a request to the server with the table information, MainApp receives an image and updates the page accordingly. Should I not use `image` state to store the URL?

One way to do this is to use `setState` in `componentWillUpdate` and use `shouldComponentUpdate` with logic based on a globalVariable (`shouldComponentUpdate` would be called multiple times) but I'm pretty sure that is probably not the recommended approach.

```
var globalVariable = true
var MainApp = React.createClass({
    shouldComponentUpdate : function () {
    // logic here using globalVariable
    }
    componentWillUpdate : function () {
        console.log("Get image from server")
        fetch('/api/data',  {
         method: 'POST',
         body: JSON.stringify({
                  tableData: this.state.tableData,
         })
        })
            .then(function(response) {
                return response.blob();
            }.bind(this))
             .then(function(imageBlob) {
                 this.setState({
                     image: URL.createObjectURL(imageBlob),
                     tableData: this.state.tableData
                 })
             }.bind(this))
         },
     handleTableUpdate : function(newState) {
            this.setState({
                image: this.state.image,
                tableData: newState
            });
            console.log("Table updated")
      },
    render : function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div id="inverter-table" className="col-sm-6">
                    <MyReactBootstrapTable
                            onTableUpdate={this.handleTableUpdate}
                            data={this.state.tableData} />
                </div>                
                <div id="img" className="col-sm-6">
                    <MyPlot url={this.state.image}></MyPlot>
                </div>
            </div>
           );
      }
    })
```

Comment: Why don't you make the `fetch` call inside `handleTableUpdate`?

Comment: That would work! I was just curious about best react practices. If you have any suggestions that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify the changed property in componentWillReceiveProps and then call setState accordingly. This will not create recursion in the code.